# How is Match Tolerance calculated for the Change Color Effect?

Tags: after-effects, effects, special-effects, visual-effects

I am studying the Change Color effect in After Effects. Do you know what the math is behind the calculation of Match Tolerance?
I read the documentation and what I gathered from it was that, say Match Tolerance is 10%, then any color that is withint 10% of the 'Color to Change' will also be included and modified accordingly.

However, how does the math for Match Tolerance work? I tried to do the calculation myself by calculating percentages from the hex values, but was not able to work the math out.